# Only draw points that are in the grid (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to only draw those points that are on the grid. I know that I just need to bound the arguments of the vector (point) and combine that with an if statement. But nothing seems to work and I always get compiler errors that I don't understand. I tried something like

> \ifnum point[0] < 5 ... \fi

which also lead nowhere. This of course is a uncomplete description of the if-statement I have in mind, but even this doesn't work probably because of syntax problems

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please post the code of your TikZ picture, not a partial screenshot of it. You could probably just do `\clip (-4.5,-4.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);` right before the dots. `\ifnum point[0]` is not a thing in TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use some really big dots, I'd just use a clip.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
\coordinate (Bone) at (1, 2);
\coordinate (Btwo) at (1,-1);
\draw[help lines] (-4.9, -4.9) grid (4.9, 4.9);
\path[->, very thick, gray] (left:5) edge (right:5) (down:5) edge (up:5);

\begin{scope}
\clip (-4.5, -4.5) rectangle (4.5, 4.5);
\tikzset{x=(Bone), y=(Btwo)}
\foreach \i in {-2, ..., 2}
  \foreach \j in {-3, ..., 3}
    \filldraw (\i, \j) circle[radius=3pt];
\draw[dashed, red, fill=gray, fill opacity=.5]
  (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle; % or with the named coordinates
\end{scope}
\draw[<->, ultra thick, red] (Btwo) node[below right] {$b_2$}
                 -- (0,0) -- (Bone) node[above  left] {$b_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]